# Both Scanner and BufferedReader not reading the first line of file in unicode format

Tags: java, input, unicode, java.util.scanner

I have tried reading file contents line by line using BufferedReader. Then, i tried with scanner also. The problem is, **If i read the file in unicode format, the first line is not read**. Please help. I used Tamil with Latha font.

My code:

**with bufferedreader**

```
File SourceFile=new File("D:/sample.txt");
FileInputStream f1=new FileInputStream(SourceFile);
BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f1, "UTF8"));
LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(SourceFile));
lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
int lines=lnr.getLineNumber();
    lnr.close();
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    { 
        System.out.println(s);
    }
br1.close();
```

Comment: You are not using `BufferedReader br1` in any way?!, you just open and close it. `LineNumberReader` (what ever that is.. edit: oh, standard Java since 1.1) on the other hand reads directly from the source file without a parameter that specifies "UTF-8", which may or may not be a problem. Also what is `s` and why do you print it in a loop?

Comment: Clueless question..double check code before submitting.